# How to attach/interface an ARM Cortex SoC with an stm32 processor

Tags: arm, stm32, linux

I'm trying to work out the best way to attach / interface an stm32f processor with a Linux based ARM SoC?

Is it possible for the stm32 to communicate with the ARM SoC via I2C ...are there any examples of stm32 acting as an I2C client talking to a Linux controller/Kernel Device Driver?

Ideally, I would like be able to upload new firmware to the stm32 from the Linux ARM SoC.

All links, tips and flaming appreciated.

Bruce

Comment: There are nearly countless options, but asynchronous serial (ie using "UART" peripherals) and USB may be among the best fits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

STM32's have a serial bootloader built in.  See http://www.scienceprog.com/flashing-programs-to-stm32-embedded-bootloader/

STMicro makes a Flash tool to get at the bootloader.  If you can find a version that runs under Linux, do some switching to put the STM32 into bootloading mode, and set up uart comms between your chips, you're good to go.

[Cross platform Flash Tool for STM32](https://code.google.com/p/stm32flash/)

Comment: Thanks Scott!! I wanted to confirm there were no well known I2C or SPI methods. I also don't have a spare UART, however as this is a Linux system I'll try MAX3109 which provides dual UART via SPI.